# Load image asynchronously from Mysql to WPF

Tags: .net, mysql, wpf, xaml

I wan't to know the best method to load image asynchronously from Mysql in a WPF application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the `ThreadPool` to load the image from the database.**

- On the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), queue the load of the image from the database;
- When the image is loaded, still in the thread pool, convert the image into an `ImageSource` using [`BitmapFrame.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615996.aspx);
- Using [`Dispather.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509.aspx), set the `Image` property to the loaded image.

So, something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LoadImage, new LoadImageRequest { ImageName = "Image.png", Control = image1 });
}

private void LoadImage(object state)
{
    var request = (LoadImageRequest)state;

    byte[] data = ...; // load bytes from the database using request.ImageName

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var imageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action<ImageSource>(p => request.Control.Source = p), imageSource
        );
    }
}

private class LoadImageRequest
{
    public string ImageName;
    public Image Control;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but i forgot to say i can't use dispatcher (or i don't know how), i'm loading images from a class.

Comment: You have to use the dispatcher. There is no way around that. If you load the image from a different thread (asynchronous), there is only one way to get the image back to the UI, and that is through the dispatcher. The example shows how.